# Remove parenthesis if length > max length

Tags: regex

I have a number of models like

```
"Dell Inspiron 6 (i7-8550U/8GB/256GB/Radeon 520/FHD/W10)"
"Lenovo V130 (i5-7200U/4GB/128GB/FHD/W10) (2017)"
"Dell XPS 13 Touch (i7-8550U/16GB/512GB/UHD/W10)"
```

and I want to remove the parenthesis where it mentions the specs.

The final output should be something like this

```
"Dell Inspiron 6"
"Lenovo V130 (2017)"
"Dell XPS 13 Touch"
```

I managed to get the parenthesis contents with this regex

```
\((.+?)\)
```

However, the regex returns both parentheses.

Is there any way to only get the text that is greater than a number of characters?

[Here is a regex example.](https://regex101.com/r/KDnHbS/1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use this regex to match `(...)` where there are 6+ characters between `(` and `)`:

```
\s*\(([^)]{6,})\)
```

[Updated RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/KDnHbS/2)

**RegEx Details:**

- `[^)]`: matches any character except `)`
- `{6,}`: Quantifier to match 6 or more characters

Comment: The only one that worked the way I needed it. (Also the simpler one.) Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use a regex substitution, and sub in an empty string.  For example, in Python, you could do the following:

```
import re

name = 'Dell Inspiron 6 (i7-8550U/8GB/256GB/Radeon 520/FHD/W10)'
re.sub("\s\(.{5,}\)", "", name)
```

**Output**

```
'Dell Inspiron 6'
```

Note that I used `{5,}` which will match only parathentical strings with 5 or more characteres, which will leave the years (e.g., (2017)) in place.

Answer (score 0):

You can exploit some text that is surely there in your first brackets and not in second brackets like a slash `/` and change your regex from,

```
\((.+?)\)
```

to

```
 \((.*\/[^)]*?)\)
```

And replace it with empty string.

**[Live Demo](https://regex101.com/r/AZEk14/2)**

Comment: The 3 models I posted is just a small part of the array. Not all model's parenthesis start with an i. I should have mentioned that.

Comment: There are many ways where you can utilize any thing in that specs bracket which is not there in second bracket to avoid getting second bracket matched, like use of `/` in specs bracket. Let me update my regex to not just depend on `i` as the starting text in brackets.